# Zero as a repeated permental root for a matrix over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, permanent

All, 
Suppose $A \in Mat(n, \mathbb{F}_{q})$ for $q$ prime, $q \geq 5$, and $n \geq 2^{q-2}$ . Let $\pi_A(x)$ be the permanental polynomial for $A$. That is, 
\begin{equation*}
\pi_{A}(x)=per(xI-A).
\end{equation*}
My question is this: if $x=0$ is a root of $\pi_A$ of multiplicity at least $q-2$, does this imply that $A$ is not invertible?

I am working on a problem recreationally and I am unable to proceed without the answer to the above question being in the affirmative (intuitively, I believe this to be the case). However, I have found no useful literature on the subject of permanental roots of matrices over finite fields, and I am at a loss as to how to progress. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess that your matrix comes from a graph, and that the permental polynomial is the one of the graph, right ?

Comment: Not necessarily. This question is a minor facet of my attempted proof of the ["AJT Conjecture"](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/a_nowhere_zero_point_in_a_linear_mapping). I considered thinking of the matrices as graphs, but it didn't prove fruitful.